# how to get dynamic data into array and append it to dom vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to append my the data that i clicked, but I get the same output as undefined.

```
<template>
<aside> 
    <ul>
        <li v-for="link in links" > </li>
           <button @click="tabLinks" v-text="link.textName" >  </button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</aside>
</template>
```

this is my script file

```
export default {
    data(){
        return {
         links : [
            {textName: 'Link 1',icon: 'fa-user fa'},
            {textName: 'link 2',icon: 'fa-search fa'},
            {textName: 'link 3',icon: 'fa-thrash fa'}
            ],
        }
    },
    methods: {
        tabLinks(){
            this.links.push({textName: this.textName  })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few errors in your code.

For example in the method `tabLinks`, you are pushing an object, but `this.textName` is not passed, it will not take automatically as you clicked on that button, one option can be to pass it ini the method.

In your HTML, you have closed `</li>` twice.

You can see these rectification and working code here: https://fiddle.jshell.net/mimani/x6ndwj8u/1/

**Modified HTML**:

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="link in links">
    <button @click="tabLinks(link.textName)">{{link.textName}}</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Updated method:**

```
  methods: {
    tabLinks(textName) {
      this.links.push({
        textName: textName
      })
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html structure is incorrect. There is a redundant `</li>` tag

```
<aside> 
    <ul>
        <li v-for="link in links" > </li> <-- remove this
           <button @click="tabLinks" v-text="link.textName" >  </button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</aside>
```

also this will not work

```
this.links.push({ textName: this.textName  })
```

because there is no `this.textName`. I'm not sure what you are trying to do, maybe you will want to pass a parameter to your `tabLinks` method.